# selecting data from three table in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three table order ,product and customer in order customer_id and product_id is foreign key how i will get all columns of order record in one query mean customer name price ,quantity total price

Comment: use join on the tables

Comment: Welcome to SO!  There are few simple things you can do to increase the odds of getting an answer.  First add some records to your question.  Then the expected output.  Finally have a go yourself.  If it doesn't work add your code and an explanation of what went wrong.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

use **`JOIN`**

```
 select orders.*, products.*, customers.*
    from order as orders
      join product as products
         on products.id = orders.product_id
      join customer as customers
         on customers.id = orders.customer_id
```

Comment: Thanks Guy's i got it   may you have a wanted future.

Answer (score 0):

use some query with Join as follows

```
SELECT * FROM product p inner join  customer c on p.product_id=c.customer_id  inner join order o on p.product_id=o.order_id
```

or

```
SELECT customername,price,quantity,totalprice FROM product p inner join  customer c on p.product_id=c.customer_id inner join order o on p.product_id=o.order_id
```

Comment: Thanks Guy's i got it   may you have a wanted future.

Comment: Please up the vote and mark as correct if its useful to you :)